# Excel: Need a lookup that looks through multiple columns and finds the first row with the desire value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have data in columns A:D. I would like the formula to search through B:D to find the value I have in E1 and output the 1st row with the value from column A. I would like the value to be populated in F1.

So for example:

```
Month   H1  H2  H3

April   4   3   5

May     5   2   4

June    30  3   11
```

If E1=5 I want the formula to populate "April", because it's the first 5 that was found in the row within the selected columns.

If E1=3 I want the formula to populate April, even though there is a 3 in June.

I would be really grateful if anyone can assist. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$D$4)/($B$1:$D$4=E1),1))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Hey Scott, this code is pretty cool. I learned a lot from using the aggregate function. This formula works very well until the chart starts to venture off into another located like if the header were to start at row 5 instead of row 1 like in my previous example. 

I have made a small modification to the formula listed below:
=INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$D$4)/($B$1:$D$4=E1),1))

That's my little tweak to the formula, but if you do see any other way around that please share :)

Comment: If you start on any other row than the first you will need to make a small mathamatical compensation on `ROW($B$1:$D$4)` you will need to subtract one less than the starting row.  For example if it starts on 5 like you said then `(ROW($B$5:$D$9)-4)`

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & MIN(MATCH(E1,$B$1:$B$6,0),MATCH(E1,$C$1:$C$6,0),MATCH(E1,$D$1:$D$6,0)))
```

This formula references the cell in column A in the row that has the first occurrence of the value in column E and the row of the formula. Paste this down column F, and you should see the following behavior:

[image]